# Set touch cordinates in android

Tags: android, touch

I have a some kind of problem that is to trigger touch event on android using X and Y coordinates or set that coordinates to trigger touch event?

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You want to trigger a touch event programmatically?

Comment: Yes I want to trigger touch event programmatically on specific coordination point. for example when I click a button it triggers click event in another position which is specified exact coordination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to trigger a click on another view you can use `View.performClick()`

If you want to trigger a touch event on exact coordinates you could create a MotionEvent

```
MotionEvent event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, action, x, y, pressure, size, metaState, xPrecision, yPrecision, deviceId, edgeFlags);

onTouchEvent(event);
```